# No. of redis client connections is getting equals to no. of instances passenger forks even though after_fork is not being placed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fork, passenger

There has been a lot of discussions around :
Passenger forking *copies* the file descriptors and external datastore connections and hence re-establishing such connections after_fork is a must.

I wanted to experiment the same with redis. 
Hence started my local redis server with no clients connected to it. 
Then I've started the passenger with 8 max-instances from my application. 
I had made sure that after_fork, redis connection re-establishment is NOT in place.

Now, as per the documentation, when the instances are forked, they should use the same connection to the redis which got created by the application loader. 
Where as, I could see 8 active client connections to redis when all the 8 max instances are up which means that no. of active client connections equals to the no. of redis active client connections.

Doesn't fork creating a new redis connection here as well? 
That's why the no. of client connection to redis is equivalent to the no. of instances here right.

I'm confused here. plz, suggest. Couldn't reproduce the fork side effects of using the same redis connection.

```
Passenger version : 5.0.23
Redis version : 2.2.2
```

**PS:** Is this something to do with passenger / redis version ? Please suggest.

Comment: May I know why is this question down voted so that I can re-work on my questioning skills ?
I've asked a valid question that i'm facing presently at work and I really want to know what's happening with the redis connections when the passenger fork happens.

Answer (score 1):

Passenger author here. What you are seeing may be a result of the specific Redis client library you are using. While I have not extensively examined the available Redis libraries, it is possible that some of them automatically detect forking and automatically reestablish connections. Another possibility is that your Redis library does not actually establish a connection until you send a Redis command -- in which case, as long as the code that runs inside the application loader (i.e. everything called from config/application.rb) does not send a Redis connection, you are fine.